# GStreamer mpegtsmux + udpsink, very slow restart in case of sender going offline

Tags: gstreamer, mpeg2-ts, gstreamer-1.0

I'm streaming a sequence of H264 mp4 files without reencoding using mpegtsmux over UDP. I previously had problems with streaming raw RTP H264 over UDP so I switched to MPEGTS, which worked out far better for me.

The only problem I have now, is that when there is a gap on the sender side, the receivers sometimes take a very long time to catch up (hanging on the previous frame). Sometimes it's even 20 seconds, sometimes it's almost instant. I need this to be as fast as possible. That's how it was working when streaming h264 over RTP, but it unfortunately produced different problems.

This is my sending pipeline (using `gst-launch-1.0`):

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! video/x-h264,stream-type=byte-stream ! mpegtsmux alignment=7 ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=238.0.0.1 port=1234
```

The receiving side:

```
udpsrc uri=udp://238.0.0.1:1234 buffer-size=65535 caps=\"application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000, pt=33\" timeout=1000000000 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsparse ! tsdemux ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink"
```

I'm not using rtpjitterbuffer as it was causing multiple problems for me. The stream is working fine though, all I needed was to add a queue before decodebin.

The receiving side is a C++ application using `gst_parse_launch` which gives me some possibilities of manipulating the stream.

I logged all messages coming from the pipeline, and I can see that a `GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT` message "`pat`" comes from `mpegtsparse` as soon as the sending side recovers, but there is a huge delay until the receivers begins to play the stream (multiple seconds), sometimes I even see there are `GST_MESSAGE_TAG` messages being received from the stream, but it's still not being played.
And when it finally starts to play - it happens in the same moment on all receiving sides, as if there was some event that triggers it, but I havent seen anything in the logs.

I tried playing with the sender's `mpegtsmux` parameters like `pmt-interval` etc but nothing changed, it's not the senders fault because when receiver is launched mid-stream then it starts playing almost instantly.

So I started looking for a way to restart the receiving side when it looses data, I added the `timeout` parameter to `udpsrc` and I can succesfully see the timeout messages when sender stops streaming, I then tried to re-start the receiver in multiple ways when the first `pat` is received from `mpegtsparse`, but without luck. These are the methods I tried:

1. Un-refing the pipeline and setting it's state to NULL, then re-creating it. This worked but produced some memory leaks and the references weren't cleared (every re-start the numbers were increasing, i.e. `udpsink1`, `udpsink2` etc.)
2. Putting the pipeline into NULL & PLAYING state when receiving first data after timeout, but this resulted in an error about udpsrc being not linked
3. Putting the pipeline into PAUSED on timeout and on next `GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED` put it to PLAYING. This worked but produced no effects, as the delay is the same. I can see the `pat` message received, and the state is set to PLAYING but the pipeline actually changes state after a few seconds, and then starts playing correctly (so there is something keeping the pipeline from playing which causes this delay). I also tried seeking to 0 before playing, but still same.

The problem doesn't appear when I restart the receiving process - it catches up instantly, so there must be something in the pipeline that keeps the pipeline waiting instead of resuming. I also noticed that the longer the stream gap is - the longer it takes for the receivers to catch up, but if they eventually do then it happens on all of them at the same time.

Is there any way I can force the pipeline to re-start or drop all the previous stream info and start over from the fresh data?